# Clearing a jquery document.ready() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How do I clear out anonymous functions that are set to trigger via a jQuery `document.ready()` call?

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //some code sets a doc ready callback
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        alert('ready');
    });
    
    //my attempt to prevent the callback from happening
    window.onload = null;
    $(document).unbind("ready");
    
</script>
```

The alert happens regardless of my attempts to circumvent it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's possible to set more than one ```ready``` function, so I'm not surprised that ```unbind``` doesn't work. A hacky solution would be to set a global variable, and wrap everything inside the ```ready``` function in an ```if``` to test the value - just change the value and while the ```ready``` function will still run, it's contents won't...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd probably get the most appropriate answer if you described what problem you're really trying to solve.

jQuery doesn't have a publicly documented way to undo or block document.ready() handlers.  If you control the code, you can use a global variable and a conditional like this:

```
var skipReady = false;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    if (!skipReady) {
        alert('ready');
    }
});

// skip the document.ready code, if it hasn't already fired
skipReady = true;
```

Or, if you want to hack into jQuery a bit (beyond the documented interfaces), you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("ready");
});

// stop the ready handler
$.isReady = true;
```

You can see this last one work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZjH2k/.  This works because jQuery uses the property: `$.isReady` to keep track of whether it has already fired the ready handlers or not.  Setting it to true makes it think it has already fired them so it won't every do it again.

Comment: I do not control the code. I'm creating a javascript snippet that can be included onto a client's website that will replace some of their content. Unfortunately they have callbacks that are expecting some of the replaced content to be there, hence an error. I figured if I could override their doc ready calls somehow, then this would solve the issue.

Comment: Wow - you're trying to block all jQuery.ready initialization code.  I hope you know what you're doing because lots of things can break if you do that.  What about legitimate init code that does need to run?  Anyway, I added one other option that can be done without modifying the code inside the ready handler.  It seems to me like you should let the regular ready code and regular page content run and THEN, after it has executed, you replace stuff in the page.

Comment: Yeah, I understand how this appears scary, but we have permission to do this. I'm open to hacking into jquery a bit, but we do have some other code that does needs to run on doc.ready. The 2nd example seems to do exactly what I need...although it seems counter-intuitive - setting isready to true would make me think that we're triggering doc.ready...

Comment: If you look at the jQuery source, `isReady` is just a flag that it uses to keep track of whether it has already run the ready handlers or not so that it never runs them more than once.  It does not trigger it.  It does this because there are multiple events that can trigger it and it wants to go only on the first event that fires.

Comment: Perfect - $.isReady is exactly what I needed. I know it's a bit hacky, but I'd rather have a hacky solution that doesn't output errors than a 'legit' solution that fails.

Comment: There is a publicly documented way to hold off executing the functions bound to `$(document).ready(fn)`, using `$.holdReady(bool)`. Pass it `true` to make them wait, then pass `false` to let them fire. Added in jQuery 1.6 - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
$(document).bind("ready", function () { alert("hey!"); });
$(document).unbind("ready");
```

Seems like a bug to me - all other events in jQuery are able to be unbound.  Omitting this one is inconsistent.

Not a direct answer as to the omission, but here's some related info from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - `$(document).ready(handler)`
> - `$().ready(handler)` (this is not recommended)
> - `$(handler)`
>
> There is also `$(document).bind("ready", handler)`. This behaves similarly to the ready method but with one exception: If the ready event has already fired and you try to `.bind("ready")` the bound handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

Comment: Nice! So I wonder what the difference is between calling $(document).ready(...) vs. $(document).bind("ready",...). Too bad the unbind documentation says it only affects those callbacks that have been set via a bind() call.

Comment: @ShaneN - The difference is that `.bind("ready", handler)` handlers will not be called if the `ready` event has already fired.  They are also called last, after any handlers bound in the more common way.

Comment: As best I can tell from looking at the source, the `$(document).bind("ready")` handlers will get called after the other ready handlers and they are the only ones that can be removed with `$(document).unbind()`.  You can't remove a `$(document).ready()` handler with unbind as they are stored differently.

Answer (score 1):

Super old question, but came across the need to do this recently to prevent document.ready code I didn't control from running in certain instances. This can be achieved by proxying jQuery's ready function, rather like a test spy. The following will work:

```
var ready = $.prototype.ready;

// proxy the ready function
$.prototype.ready = function ( fn, allowed ) {
    allowed = allowed || false;

    if ( allowed ) {
        ready.call( this, fn );
    }
};
```

All calls to `$( document ).ready` will now be ignored. You can override this behaviour by passing true as the second argument: `$( document ).ready( fn, true )`

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready() is dependent on the onLoad event which is triggered by the browser meaning you can not prevent it from happening.  If the alert() is determined by some condition then I would use an if/else statement to decide whether it is called.

Comment: This is not the case.  $(document).ready() is generated by jQuery and there are ways to stop it from happening.