# Prevent jQuery ready handlers from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a situation where in a certain condition, I want whatever jQuery `ready` handlers have been bound not to actually fire on the `DOMContentReady` event. These handlers are bound in various places, including various include files, plugins and so on. So while I could set some kind of global variable in a script near the top of my page, and put an `if` condition to check for this variable in front of every `$(document).ready()` binding, I'd rather not.

Ideally I'm looking for one of two things,

- a property I could set on the jQuery object before the includes that would tell it to ignore calls to `.ready()`
- a method I could call towards the end of the document, in an inline script before `DOMContentReady` has fired, to unbind the `ready()` handlers.

The obvious one, `$(document).unbind('ready')` doesn't do it, I guess because `.ready()` isn't an ordinary event binding.

Can this be done? If so, how?

One vague idea I had would be to extend the jQuery prototype, and replace `ready()` with a method that would check a new property that I would introduce. Does that make sense?

Comment: Where are you putting your `unbind` code ? If you putting it before `ready` function, it is not supposed to `unbind` it. If you are putting it inside or after `ready` function. It has been called already. You can return `false` inside `ready` function, if particular condition is matched.

Comment: No, the issue is that calls to `$(document).ready()` don't get unbound by `$(document).unbind('ready')`. I'm not sure why exactly.

Comment: I can clarify you , if you can show your code. Btw, it looks that you have already found an answer

Comment: Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/BFUHH/) , if this rings a bell. You cannot `unbind` the future handler. I assume that you are unbinding before the `ready` function call.

Comment: I understand that. The point is that for `ready()` specifically, calling `unbind('ready')` at *any* point does not prevent the `ready()` handler from firing. See http://jsfiddle.net/bC7YY/

Comment: Oh, I get it.

See the answer no 1 and 2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814408/clearing-a-jquery-document-ready-call/) , excellent solutions. Also, the bug described [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1311), which has the same fix.

Comment: Well, `$(document).bind('ready')` is deprecated as of 1.8, and also some of the `ready()` calls may be in third-party plugins. Hence I was looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should use [holdready](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/)

```
$.holdReady(true);
$.getScript("myplugin.js", function() {
  $.holdReady(false);
});
```

Comment: That looks promising. I don't have my dev environment in front of me at this moment, but I think it's exactly what I need.

Comment: Yet another hidden feature of jQuery. +1