# Handling multiple document ready event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I have multiple document ready event listeners in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("hello james")
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("hello cindy")
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("hello dave")
});
```

I only want the first document ready to call when the user visits the page. I do not need the other two document readies to call.

I can't use a global variable to check for this. What I'm hoping to do is use `bind`. My theory is that by setting the code to...

```
$(document).bind("ready", function() {
  console.log("hello james")
});

$(document).bind("ready", function() {
  console.log("hello cindy")
});


$(document).bind("ready", function() {
  console.log("hello dave")
});
```

Only the first bind will call. That's my current understanding of how `bind` works.

Now, here is the kicker. What I need to happen is once these binds run (again I only expect the first bind to get executed and thus "hello james" print out in my console log), I need to unbind the ready document. I was thinking of doing...

```
$(document).bind("ready", function() {
  console.log("hello james")
  $(document).unbind("ready");
});

$(document).bind("ready", function() {
  console.log("hello cindy")
});


$(document).bind("ready", function() {
  console.log("hello dave")
});
```

But that does not work. "hello james" will be logged but the ready event does not unbind. Am I missing something here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this at all, something is seriously flawed if this is the only solution to some problem.

Comment: Why do you need 3 functions like this? One solution would be to only have one `$(document).ready` function, and call the other two from inside of it

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to "bind()", but your understanding appears to be different from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: I would never do this in real life, but I'm having some caching issues that is duplicating my Javascript code so I end up with multiple event listeners. I can't fix the caching issue so here I am trying to solve this convoluted problem. As for `bind()` my understanding comes from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7814473/1509401

Comment: @racraman I believe you are confusing [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) with the (deprecated) [$.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: "the ready event does not unbind"...even so, how is it fired more than once?

Comment: If the same code is duplicated from caching issues, you have to fix that problem, you can't fix it the way you're proposing.

Comment: It's only fired more than once if I'm using `(document).ready()`. I really want to be careful here and not talk about the behind the scenes or this question will get hairy. All that needs to be known is that I have to unbind the first document ready after it runs.

Comment: @adeneo, I can't fix the caching issue. I hear you loud and clear though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/).
This prevents any other handlers bound to the same event from being executed:

```js
$(document).on("ready",function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  console.log("hello james");
});
$(document).on("ready",function(){console.log("hello cindy");});
$(document).on("ready",function(){console.log("hello dave");});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6j23hao/2/**

*(I changed `.ready(` to `.on("ready",` because otherwise both the code snippet and the jsfiddle would not work / generate an error, though I don't understand why. As far as I can tell `.ready(` should work just fine.)*